# Hibernate - on the stack or on the heap?

Tags: hibernate, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

As a Java programmer, you usually keep two truths in your pocket:

- Instance variables and Objects lie on Heap.
- Local variables and methods lie on the Stack.

Now that I use Hibernate in just about everything, I realize I'm not as sure of myself.

Are there some good rules of thumb for using hibernate and knowing where your memory lives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean. I do know that all objects (Hibernate or other), even if you only have a local reference to them, go on the heap.

I'd worry more about the correctness of your code than this sort of thing, I doubt it'll noticeably affect performance. One database query would dwarf the possible speed difference.